# Why do I need to reference this-> on a convert constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop, this

I'm still learning the basics of OOP in C++, and a question has emerged when creating an operator method with a convert constructor.

Here's my code:

**Header file:**

```
class Integer {
private:
    int num;
public:
    Integer();
    Integer(int);//Convert constructor
    ~Integer();
    operator int();
    int getNum();
};
```

**Source file:**

```
Integer::operator int() {
   return this->num; //No idea why I need to specify this-> here.
}
```

**`main` method:**

```
Integer a(50); 
a = 100;       

int b = (int)a; 
cout << b << endl;
```

So my question is, why do I need to use `this->` on the `operator int()` method? I'm not passing any conflicting parameters so it shouldn't be a problem to the compiler. Also I tested it without, and it worked fine. But in my the textbook I'm following it explicitly says that I should add the `this->num`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which textbook are you using?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need the cast in `int b = (int)a;`. `int b = a;` will work just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the particular example that you've shown here you don't actually need to use the `this->` prefix. There are only a few cases where you need to prefix data members with `this->`, such as

- if you want to reference a data member with the same name as a local variable or parameter to a member function, or
- if you're using templates and inheritance together and need to look something up in the base class.

Since the example you have doesn't fall into these cases, as you noted in your own exploration, the `this->` prefix is totally optional.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

`this` is a pointer to your class.

`*this` is your class content.

---

Arrow operator: `x->y` is equivalent to `(*x).y` , just in a neater way.

Comment: I suspected that "this" was a pointer, but had no idea we could actually specify it as such! Thank you